# Multiple apps are getting submitted to spark Cluster and keeps in waiting and then exits withError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am submitting a spark application to the Cluster by using the following command

```
/root/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.momory=10g --class com.knoldus.SampleApp /pathToJar/Application.jar
```

But what is happening is : Multiple apps are getting submitted and one is running and all others are waiting and then after sometime the code exits with an exception.

The Spark UI looks something like this :

[image]

After this the code exits with this error :

```
8.149.243): java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to keyspace.tableName.
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:167)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/12/14 06:26:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 561, 10.178.149.243): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/12/14 06:26:28 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 563, 10.178.149.225): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1904)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.knoldus.xml.RNF2Driver$.main(RNFIngestPipeline.scala:56)
    at com.knoldus.xml.RNF2Driver.main(RNFIngestPipeline.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Spark-conf is :

```
  private val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("SampleApp")
    .setMaster(sparkClusterIP)
    .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "8")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraIP)
    .set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
    .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "640m")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
    .set("spark.executor.cores", "3")
    .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.rows", "10")
    .set("spark.cassandra.output.batch.size.bytes", "20480")
```

This is my sample code. Can anyone please let me know what the problem is :

```
  val cassandraIDs = sc.cassandraTable[A](keySpace,tableName).map(_.filename.split("/").last.split("\\.")(0).toLong).collect()
    val broadCastList = sc.broadcast(cassandraIDs)
    val files = sc.wholeTextFiles(hdFSIP).map(_._1).filter { path =>
      val listOfCassandraID = broadCastList.value
      !listOfCassandraID.contains(path.split("/").last.split("\\.")(0).toLong)
    }.take(100)

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val fileNameRDD = sc.parallelize(files)

    val cassandraRdd = fileNameRDD.map { path =>
     ...

    //do some task

    }.toDF(columnNames)

    cassandraRdd.saveToCassandra(keySpace,tablename)
    println(s"Completed Processing of $numOfDocs in ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start} milliseconds")

  sc.stop()
```

Comment: how many nodes cluster is that ? Are you running spark in standalone mode ?

Comment: There are two workers and one master ! It is in cluster mode !!

Comment: What is the cluster capacity? If cluster capacity is less, reduce values of 'spark.executor.cores' and 'spark.executor.memory'.

Answer (score 2):

**Why multiple apps are getting submitted?**

Because you are submitting multiple spark jobs in your driver code. Each one of the below statements will trigger a new job in the current spark context,

> val cassandraIDs = sc.cassandraTable[A]....toLong).collect()
>
> sc.wholeTextFiles
>
> sc.parallelize(files)
>
> cassandraRdd.saveToCassandra(keySpace,tablename)
>
> .toDF(columnNames)
>
> sc.broadcast

(Not sure about the last two)

I haven't worked with cassandra via spark much. But, above code doesn't utilize the power of spark.
You should pipeline the tasks as much as possible, so that spark can plan and run the tasks in distributed way.

**Example:**

In your code, you are creating `files` by calling `take(100)` and then creating an RDD called `fileNameRDD` using `sc.parallelize(files)`.

This triggers two spark jobs, one to take 100 items, and one to create a new RDD using those 100 items.

Instead you should combine these two tasks so that they can be pipelined by spark.

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(hdFSIP).map(_._1).filter { path =>
  val listOfCassandraID = broadCastList.value
  !listOfCassandraID.contains(path.split("/").last.split("\\.")(0).toLong)

}.map { path =>    /*<---Combine the two tasks like this*/
 ...

//do some task

}.toDF(columnNames)
```

*Note:* I have skipped `take(100)` part, but you should be able to do that using filters

**Why are you getting `NoSuchElementException: None.get` error**

This is more likely because of **scala version mismatch** between your code and the scala version that is used to build the spark.

Comment: I am not new to spark. It would be great if you could elaborate how my answer didn't help you. Did you find it hard to understand? or did you try my solution and didn't find any improvement?
Also, I would like to know how experience you  have with spark so that I can  narrow down the possible solutions to you.